# How to take out array from array and assign it to another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays.

I am trying to write code in javascript for following psedocode.

```
Take the length of array of arrays

take out each array from array and assign it to new array
```

like as following which is not correct.

```
    for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.Permissions.length; i++) 
        var arr + [i] = $scope.Permissions[i];
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the individual arrays to a single, "long" array?

Comment: you can't dynamically create variables like that. you can dynamically assign properties to an object (the scope object for example like described in one of the answers below).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array's builtin forEach method:

`$scope.Permissions.forEach(function (arr, i) { $scope['arr' + i] = arr });`

Answer (score 0):

In your case it makes sense to create bunch of new arrays as properties of the `$scope` object:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.Permissions.length; i++) {
    $scope['arr' + i] = $scope.Permissions[i];
}

console.log($scope.arr0, $scope.arr1);
```

Comment: i got this error in console: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: What is `$scope.Permissions`? Check `console.log($scope.Permissions)`.

Comment: @ dfsq. My mistake it works fine as u suggested. thanks